# Warning for `incomplete-patterns` in visual studio code for haskell

Tags: haskell

How do you get the [visual studio haskell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell) extension to warn about **incomplete-patterns**   ?

I don't see such a settings on VS code side.  [haskell-language-server](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server) has a `pedantic` plugin, disabled by default. Which I imagine can spot `incomplete-patterns`, just like `stack build --pedantic` can when building.

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

module SOQuestionIncomplete0 where

data Sum s t a = Inl (s a) | Inr (t a)

injs :: Sum s t a -> t a
injs (Inr ta) = ta -- incomplete, no warning

-- >>>   injs (Inl [1 :: Int]) :: [Int]
-- /src/SOQuestionIncomplete0.hs:9:1-18: Non-exhaustive patterns in function injs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = injs (Inl [1 :: Int]) :: [Int]
  putStrLn $ "Hello, World!" ++ show a
```

Comment: If everything else fails, you should be able to add something like `{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}` near the top of your file before the `module` line. It would be better to put that in a cabal/stack file, if any, or in some "GHC options" field of the VS plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The most favoured approach is always to add flags such as this to the `ghc-options` in your cabal or stack file.

If you've got a project with no cabal file, add a file named `hie.yaml` to the project directory, with the following contents:

```
cradle:
  direct:
    arguments: ["-Wincomplete-patterns"]
```